0000:05:00.0: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping
I get these below errors while using the DL360 gen 9 10gig nic's on Ubuntu 24.04
"[ 487.089476] vfio-pci 0000:05:00.0: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping. Contact your platform vendor.
[ 487.089676] vfio-pci 0000:05:00.1: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping. Contact your platform vendor.
[ 487.089802] vfio-pci 0000:08:00.0: Firmware has requested this device have a 1:1 IOMMU mapping, rejecting configuring the device without a 1:1 mapping. Contact your platform vendor.
"
=> Interestingly below NIC's running firware version - "firmware-version: 0x0001546c" are working fine
pci@0000:82:00.0 ens3f0 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:82:00.1 ens3f1 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
=> Where as below NIC's running firmware version - "firmware-version: 0x800008ea" are not working with above mentioned error
pci@0000:05:00.0 ens2f0 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:05:00.1 ens2f1 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:08:00.0 ens1f0 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:08:00.1 ens1f1 network 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue - the only thing I can think of is to upgrade these non working NIC's firmware to "firmware-version: 0x0001546c", team could you please help me to the same.
FYI: I am running Ubuntu 24.04 OS
Things already tried:
#1 Ugrading the kernel version - no help
#2 also tried the resolution at "https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/qemu-exited-with-code-1-pcie-passthrough-not-working.146297/" - no help
